# Reshaping data with missing values

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks similar to this...

```
Id  Disease     Gene    Mutation    Expression
101 Disease_X   Gene_A  R273G       Normal
101 Disease_X   GENE_B  G12D        Normal
102 Disease_Y   GENE_C  L858R       High
```

and I want to reshape it such that each id and gene pair is represented for both 'Mutation and Expression, even if there is no value present.

For instance, each id-gene pair would have 6 possible values (3 genes for Mutation, 3 for Expression) and if there is no value in the original table for Mutation or Expression, the output would provide some standard output for missing data to fill that row (eg. "No Mutation data"). A table output would look like this:

```
Id  Disease     Type        Gene    Value
101 Disease_X   Mutation    Gene A  R273G
101 Disease_X   Mutation    GENE B  G12D
101 Disease_X   Mutation    GENE C  No Mutation Data
101 Disease_X   Expression  Gene A  Normal
101 Disease_X   Expression  GENE B  Normal
101 Disease_X   Expression  GENE C  No Expression Data 
102 Disease_Y   Mutation    Gene A  No Mutation Data
102 Disease_Y   Mutation    GENE B  No Mutation Data
102 Disease_Y   Mutation    GENE C  L858R
102 Disease_Y   Expression  Gene A  No Expression Value
102 Disease_Y   Expression  GENE B  No Expression Value
102 Disease_Y   Expression  GENE C  High
```

I know there is an easy way to do this (using merge or melt?) but I haven't come up with anything straightforward.

Comment: Would it be possible to share a reproducible version of this input, with (for instance) `dput(head(mydata))`? It's also not clear what you mean by "missing", since there actually is no missing data in your example input. Do you mean that it has NA?

Comment: I created this model from scratch on a spreadsheet just for example purposes, so I don't have in in R but I can do that...

Comment: It would be helpful to understand in particular what you mean by "no value" in the original spreadsheet (do you mean NA?) As it is, just using reshape2's melt function gets you very close to this out of the box

Comment: Basically it means that the data we are getting is generally highlighting only those ids/genes that have changes/alterations. But we also would want to generate the data for the 'normal' values so we can generate visuals. Not sure if that helps clarify this...

Comment: You misunderstand my question: I'm asking what you mean by no value in terms of your actual R input. Your example above has no examples of missing data. Do you mean the dataset has NAs in it? (I'm not asking what those NA's represent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a few extra steps to get exactly what you seem to be looking for.

In the following, I start by making all of the combinations of "Id", "Type", and "Gene", merging that with a "long" form of your dataset, and then fixing the "Disease" column.

I've left the `NA` as `NA` since that seems to make more sense to me in case you need to do any further work.

This assumes you're starting with a dataset called "mydf".

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)

DT <- as.data.table(mydf)                                ## Convert to data.table
DTL <- melt(DT, id.vars = c("Id", "Disease", "Gene"))    ## Make it long
groups <- c("Id", "Gene", "variable")                    ## Save some typing
toMerge <- do.call(CJ, lapply(DTL[, groups,              ## Generate the combos
                                  with = FALSE], unique))
merged <- merge(DTL, toMerge, by = groups, all = TRUE)   ## merge
merged[, Disease := unique(na.omit(Disease)), by = Id][] ## Fill in Disease
#      Id   Gene   variable   Disease  value
#  1: 101 GENE_B   Mutation Disease_X   G12D
#  2: 101 GENE_B Expression Disease_X Normal
#  3: 101 GENE_C   Mutation Disease_X     NA
#  4: 101 GENE_C Expression Disease_X     NA
#  5: 101 Gene_A   Mutation Disease_X  R273G
#  6: 101 Gene_A Expression Disease_X Normal
#  7: 102 GENE_B   Mutation Disease_Y     NA
#  8: 102 GENE_B Expression Disease_Y     NA
#  9: 102 GENE_C   Mutation Disease_Y  L858R
# 10: 102 GENE_C Expression Disease_Y   High
# 11: 102 Gene_A   Mutation Disease_Y     NA
# 12: 102 Gene_A Expression Disease_Y     NA
```

Comment: @user2900006, OK. If it solved your problem, do *consider* "accepting" it.

Comment: Yes, it is solved. How do I formally "accept" it. Looking around for how to do this...

Comment: @user2900006, to the left of my answer should be a hollow check mark waiting to be clicked ;-)